# Pytorch on a fresh install of ubuntu can't find my GPU

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, gpu, nvidia, pytorch

I have the latest ubuntu 18 installed just an hour ago. I have the newest anaconda 3.7 installed maybe 20 minutes ago. Then I proceeded to use

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

but when I open use python3 it still gives me

```
alex@alex:~$ python3
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 13:15:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
>>>
```

To be sure, I do have a gpu in my computer:

```
alex@alex:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
```

I have also restarted my computer after the installing pytorch and it did not change anything. This is my second attempt at getting GPU to work on pytorch, my last attempt was on Lubuntu a few days ago using pip install and I installed some Nvidia drivers but still couldn't get it to work so i started anew.

Comment: is cuda actually installed?

Comment: i was told that cuda comes installed when u install pytorch with anaconda.

Comment: run nvcc --version on your terminal and report on the results

Comment: Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Comment: You obviously need to install cuda :)

Comment: I ran sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit just now and it has installed. again it gives torch.cuda.is_available() = False. I will try restarting and see if anythign changes.

Comment: The cuda toolkit is NOT cuda.  Visit https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads and follow the guidelines (make sure to select the correct version -- should be 9.0)

Comment: Are you sure cuda toolkit is not cuda? the link you showed me is the CUDA Toolkit 10.0 Download. I can find 9.0 in legacy releases page but it's also for cuda toolkit.

Comment: Yes. https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/862537/cuda-setup-and-installation/installing-cuda-toolkit-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Cuda 9.0 did not have ubuntu 18.0 as an option, So I had to get cuda toolkit 10.0. Then since the pytorch I got was for 9.0, i uninstalled torch and torchvision from conda and reinstalled pytorch with the cuda100 argument. However, it is still giving me torch.cuda.is_available()=False. However, nvcc --version gives nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85